# Having trouble with get/setObjectAcl to ibm cloud object storage service

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am using the ibm-cos-sdk npm to access my IBM Cloud Object Storage instance. I am successfully able to create a bucket, and put objects to it. I now need to set the ACL to `public-read`. I am having trouble with this part. I call

`cos.getBucketAcl({ Bucket })`

and get an `AccessDenied`; same for `cos.setBucketAcl({ Bucket, ACL: 'public-read' })`. I'm using the same `cos` variable that succeeds with `createBucket` and `putObject`.

I tried to use the `aws` cli, and only get this error, for *any* operation:

`[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)`

thanks,
nick

Answer (score 1):

The user or service ID needs the `manager` role in an IAM policy to make objects publicly visible.  You might only have `writer` access?

That sounds like an SSL bug - I've seen something similar in the vanilla OSX Python installation.  You might want to install a different version of Python and try again.